# Error handling in Vue JS - errors not caught

Tags: vue.js

I have the following code:

```
fooService.update(this.bar).then( this.$emit('updated', this.updatedBar),).catch(err => {...
```

If an error is encountered, then the error is not caught. If I change the code to be:

```
fooService.update(this.bar).then(x => {this.$emit('updated', this.updatedBar);}).catch(err => {...
```

Then the error is caught and shows as expected. Can anyone explain to me what is going on and why it behaves in that way?

**Edit**

Underlying service code:

```
function updateBar(bar) {
  return $http.put(`/api/bar/${bar.Id}`, bar);
}
```

Comment: Why do you combine `await` syntax with `Promise` syntax?

Comment: @Cristy oddly enough, I know someone that does the same, it does end up _ignoring_ the await in the sense it will do the `.then`, although I assume it doesn't fully ignore it.

Comment: To hazard a guess, I'd say because in the first example the `.then` is not being passed a function

Comment: @Cristy - amended the code, the same happens however it is approached.

Comment: @George do you know what is going on 'under the hood' at that point? I'd like to understand in a little more detail if possible

Comment: @Leonidas199x where is the error happening? I have a feeling it's when it's doing the `this.$emit` and not in the promise call itself

Comment: @George it should be occurring in the promise call (I believe), the error would be coming back from the service. I have hashed it so the underlying API always returns a HTTP error code.

Comment: @Leonidas199x can you post the code for `fooService.update` as I'm unable to replicate the problem you're having

Comment: @George - added the code, it is simply an abstraction to call the API so the components don't need to.

Comment: @Leonidas199x Thanks, I can't get it to replicate still but you should be doing it the second way anyway

Comment: @Leonidas199x I've posted an answer, hopefully it'll help you with _why_ the second one is right regardless of error catching and what I think may of been the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I still think the error is happening in the `this.$emit` the reason why, in

```
fooService.update(this.bar).then( this.$emit('updated', this.updatedBar),).catch(err => {
```

It has to evaluate the `this.$emit` first as you're setting the **response** from that function as the `.then` and not the call itself.

Proof of it doing that

```js
function emit(){
  console.log('emit')
}

var promise = new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('promise is done')
  reject();
}, 1000)
})

promise.then(emit()).catch( function() {console.log('carry on');})
```

notice how it logs "emit" first

Now if that errors you can see it doesn't hit the catch

```js
function emit(){
  console.log('emit')
  throw new Error("bad")
}

var promise = new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('promise is done')
  reject();
}, 1000)
})

promise.then(emit()).catch( function() {console.log('carry on');})
```

So *under the hood* it's doing this (the simplest way I can think of)

```
emit()

try{
    getService()
} catch{
    ...
}
```

Whereas if you actually pass the `.then` a function it changes the order of things

```js
function emit(){
  console.log('emit')
  throw new Error("bad")
}

var promise = new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('promise is done')
  reject();
}, 1000)
})

promise.then(() => {emit()}).catch( function() {console.log('carry on');})
```

and again *under the hood* it looks like this

```
try{
    getService()
    emit()
} catch{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to do this, really appreciate it. That pretty much answers my question.